# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT. with put forms. Laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, get, put

I actually have a problem about one of my form, which allows the user to change his profile picture.

When I submit the file, this URI is loading localhost/projetT/public/profil/icone/2 but nothing happened. If I reload the URI, because the loading is very very long, I get this error:
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT. I need help.

```
<div class="container bg-primary rounded mt-4 mb-4" style="min-height: 1300px;"">
  <div class="row p-2">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row h-50">
        <div class="col-12 justify-content-center">
          <img class="img-fluid d-block bg-dark rounded-circle h-100 mx-auto shadow-lg" src="../public/uploads/{{ Auth::user()->image }}">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form action="{{ route('profil.icone',['user' => Auth::user()]) }}" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
              <div class="row mx-md-n5">
                <div class="col">
                  <input id="avatar" type="file" class="form-control bg-white text-dark border-dark" name="avatar">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row p-3">
                <div class="col text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-dark text-white" id="enregistre" name="enregistre">Changer de photo</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="bg-dark"></hr>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form action="{{ route('profil.edit',['user' => Auth::user()]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
            <h3 class="text-light mb-4 rounded bg-dark text-center">Informations du compte</h3>
            <div class="pl-lg-6">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group focused">
                    <label class="text-dark" for="input-nom" class="text-primary">Nom</label>
                    <input type="text" id="input-nom" class="form-control validate border-dark font-weight-bold text-dark" name="nom" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" disabled="disabled" >
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group focused">
                    <label class="text-dark" for="input-prenom">Prenom</label>
                    <input type="text" id="input-prenom" class="form-control validate border-dark font-weight-bold text-dark" name="prenom" value="{{ Auth::user()->prenom }}" disabled="disabled" >
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group focused">
                    <label class="text-dark" for="input-pseudo">Pseudo</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="input-pseudo" class="form-control validate border-dark font-weight-bold text-dark" name="pseudo" value="{{ Auth::user()->pseudo }}" disabled="disabled">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="text-dark" for="input-email">Adresse Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="input-email" class="form-control validate border-dark font-weight-bold text-dark" name="mail" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" disabled="disabled">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group" id="zoneOldMDP">
                    <!-- zone qui va recevoir les champs pour l'ancien mdp -->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group" id="zoneNewMDP">
                    <!-- zone qui va recevoir les champs pour le nouveau mdp -->  
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center" id="zoneEnregistrer">
                  <input class="btn btn-default btn-dark text-white" type="button" id="modifier" name="modifier" value="Modifier">
                </div>
              </div>  
            </div> 
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, my problem is about the first form with {{ route('profil.icone',['user' => Auth::user()]) }}.

The second form with {{ route('profil.edit',['user' => Auth::user()]) }} is actually working well and update my data in database. The submit button of the second form is added in JQuery after clicking on the "Modifier" button.

But I don't understand why the first one isn't working, because the two forms are very similar, only name of action is changing.

```
class ProfilController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('profil');
    }

     public function store(ImagesRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
        ]);

        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $image = $request->file('avatar');

            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save('/uploads/' . $filename );

            $user->image = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }
        return view('profil')->with ('alert', 'Votre photo a été mise à jour');
    }

    public function storeCompte(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $nom = $request->nom;
        $prenom = $request->prenom;
        $pseudo = $request->pseudo;
        $mail = $request->mail;

        $user->name = $nom;
        $user->prenom = $prenom;
        $user->pseudo = $pseudo;
        $user->email = $mail;   

        $user->save();

        return back ()->with ('alert', 'Vos informations ont été mise à jour');
    }
}
```

There are my routes about profile; in web.php file.

```
Route::get('/profil', 'ProfilController@index')->name('profil')->middleware('auth');
//route pour mettre a jour sa photo de profil
Route::put('/profil/icone/{user}', 'ProfilController@store')->name('profil.icone');
//route pour editer son profil
Route::put('/profil/edit{user}', 'ProfilController@storeCompte')->name('profil.edit');
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: add a slash (/) on `Route::put('/profil/edit{user}` to `Route::put('/profil/edit/{user}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **a typos** you need to fix to get it working

Change this line

```
Route::put('/profil/edit{user}', 'ProfilController@storeCompte')->name('profil.edit');
```

To

```
Route::put('/profil/edit/{user}', 'ProfilController@storeCompte')->name('profil.edit');
```

Then in your blade forms

Change

```
action="{{ route('profil.icone',['user' => Auth::user()]) }}"
action="{{ route('profil.edit',['user' => Auth::user()]) }}"
```

To

```
action="{{ route('profil.icone',['user' => Auth::id()]) }}"
action="{{ route('profil.edit',['user' => Auth::id()]) }}"
```

Comment: Thx, I have edited actions, but still not working for the icon. After clicking on the button to change the photo, there is still an unfinishable loading.

Comment: You may debug your `store` function line by line using `dd('message');` to be sure your request hit the right place

Comment: yeah, but I can't because even if the store function is empty, I got the same issue, when I click on the change button, unfinishable load, and if I reload the URI, get method is not supported. Maybe the error comes from another way, don't know, this is my first project with Laravel.

Comment: Yes, you should not reload URI manually from your browser search bar cause browsers only able to send POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE request only via form submits. However you must wait for it to get the error message.

Comment: 30 min and nothing happened ... I don't know. There is probably a reason why the URI don't load.

Comment: Why don't change `ImagesRequest $request` in your store function with `Request $request`and retry ?

Comment: not working, there is also a loading, I will try another function for this route, to see if the problem come from the function, or the route or maybe something else

Comment: So, after some tests, is because of the input type="file" , if I remove the input, the route works well. Why ?

Comment: maybe it's something related to file size. Did you try to upload tiny img ?

Comment: yeah I think that was this, changed the php.ini but didn't have restarted the apache server. Thanks for the possible ways of response.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have restarted MAMP and so the apache server and the route works, I now have a 'can't write data to path' but can resolve it I guess.
Thx for help.